# <function sentence... > output on sentence generator?

Tags: python

Sorry, this may be a simple thing but I am just learning and when I try to run an example program from my textbook of a sentence generator the output I get is:

<function sentence at 0x000002B0F7CBD160>

I should instead get a sentence and I'm not sure what the hexadecimal(?) means. I have been experimenting with different programs like Pycharm and VS Code and it seemed to be working a few days ago in Pycharm but after working in VS Code I keep getting this output in both programs.

The code from the textbook:

```
import random

articles = ("A", "The")
nouns = ("boy", "girl", "bat", "ball")
verbs = ("hit", "saw", "liked")
prepositions = ("with", "by")


def sentence():
    return nounPhrase() + " " + verbPhrase() + "."


def nounPhrase():
    return random.choice(articles) + " " + random.choice(nouns)


def prepositionalPhrase():
    return random.choice(prepositions) + " " + nounPhrase()


def verbPhrase():
    return random.choice(verbs) + " " + nounPhrase() + \
           " " + prepositionalPhrase()


def main():
    number = int(input("Enter the number of sentences: "))
    for count in range(number):
        print(sentence)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex is the `id` of the `sentence` object

When you print, you're printing (probably) the memory address of the sentence function, rather than its output when you `print(sentence)` rather than `print(sentence())`

---

Also note that `generator` [means something special in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) - it's a function which builds the `next` result, rather than calculating them all at once. This can be more efficient when you do not know how many values from an iterable you need, or if each call is expensive and you want to process each result in turn (rather than waiting for every result to be ready and then processing them all afterwards)

Comment: Thank you. Your alternative fixed the issue . Do you know why it might have changed to print the id of the sentence object rather than the output of the function?

Comment: The author simply missed the parentheses on the call! `print(x)` vs `print(x())`

Comment: Ah! I just went and double checked and the problem was that *I* missed the parentheses when following along the textbook, not the author. Thank you for your help.